# Detect Android Browser Setting with JavaScript

Tags: android, flash, android-browser, mobile-browser

In the android browser you can set "Enable Plug-ins" to "Always On", "On Demand", "Off".

this leads to the fact that when a flash movie is embedded into a browser page, you need to tap on an arrow to start the movie.

now my question is, is there any way to detect this setting via javascript or similar?
so that i can embed a flashmovie or use a workaround?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `navigator.plugins` API:

```
Boolean(JSON.stringify(navigator.plugins).match(/flash/i))
```

to determine the on/off state.

The on demand state is indeterminate.

**References**

- [Flash Player guidance for Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2015/10/flash-player-guidance-for-internet-explorer-11-and-microsoft-edge.html#sthash.JYi4Gtlb.dpbs)
- [Future-Proofing Flash Player Detection Scripts | Adobe Developer Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/future_detection.html)
- [Adobe Flash Player Administration Guide for Flash Player | Adobe Developer 
  Connection](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/flash_player_admin_guide.html)
- [HTML5 by Default for Google Chrome - Flash Player - AS3Lang Community](https://discuss.as3lang.org/t/html5-by-default-for-google-chrome/291)
- [How to detect adobe flash player addon's enable/disable status in IE8 - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/499925/Howplustoplusdetectplusflashplusenable-fdisablepl)